# Display venue public photo on iOS app

Tags: api, foursquare

My apologies if I'm not using the most technical terms in my question as I am asking on behalf of a development team who is creating an app for me, but we are having trouble making a call to the Foursquare API to get public photos (at least one) of specific venues.

Until now they have only been able to get low resolution photos and are telling me we need to be authenticated but I'm not sure they are explaining what they need to me correctly.

I have searched for hours and have not been able to understand how we would be able to obtain at least one photo for a given venue. The closest I have come to is getting a list of photos for a venue using the example query: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos?oauth_token=...TOKEN...&v=20130529

This involves the OAuth_Token and I had understood we didn't need this to get an image of a venue using the API.

Once again, apologies if I'm using any terms incorrectly as I am not a programmer myself. Thanks.

Comment: please make clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

That call to venues/VENUE_ID/photos is indeed a way to solve your problem: you can do that to get public photos for specific venues, where the specific venue is identified by VENUE_ID. You don't need an OAuth token; instead, you can simply pass in `client_id` and `client_secret` parameters. Examine the URL pattern we document under "Userless access" here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless

Once you have these responses, you need to construct a photo URL, and this is where you can specify the desired size. For each photo response, you take **`prefix` + size + `suffix`** to construct a full URL. For an example, see https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo